# How to check for Previous managers in Employee History (Python)

Tags: python

I have a dataset with all employees records and need to find the most recent(which I have) and the previous manager before. I wanted to use the shift function but unfortunately not all employees have the same history layout.
Here is a small example:

```
 ID    Job_Title       Mananger 
 1       Sales         John Doe
 1       Sales         Kobe Bryant  
 1       Sales         Phil Knight
 2       Tech          Michael Jordan 
 2       Tech          Michael Jordan 
 2       Tech          Larry Bird 
 3       Sales         Magic Johnson 
 3       Sales         Magic Johnson
 3       Sales         Magic Johnson
```

And this is what I need:

```
ID    Job_Title     Manager       Previous Manager 
 1     Sales        John Doe         Kobe Bryant 
 1     Sales        Kobe Bryant      Kobe Bryant 
 1     Sales        Phil Knight      Kobe Bryant
 2     Tech         Michael Jordan   Michael Jordan   
 2     Tech         Michael Jordan   Michael Jordan 
 2     Tech         Larry Bird       Michael Jordan 
 3     Sales        Magic Johnson    Magic Johnson
 3     Sales        Magic Johnson    Magic Johnson 
 3     Sales        Magic Johnson    Magic Johnson
```

I tried using the shift function but that only works on seeing the change, I want to be able to map the previous manager.

Comment: It's not obvious how the second table should be derived from the first one alone. (How do we know Kobe Bryant precedes either John Doe or Phil Knight, and for that matter, shouldn't John or Phil precede the other even if Kobe was first?)

Comment: I get what you're saying so their needs to date to indicate that change? or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the apply function to apply the row to the current table like this:

```
import pandas
import numpy

def find_num(row):
    if row in data:
        return data[row]
    else:
        return numpy.NaN

df['Previous Manager'] = df['ID'].apply(find_num)
```